# Hello, could someone explain to me this php $_SESSION script?

Tags: php, session

could anyone explain to me this script?

```
$_SESSION['prodotto_'.$_GET['add']];
```

I can't figure out this script...isn't `$_SESSION` variable supposed to be composed by a name and a valule? Here I can see there's a name "prodotto"...but what's the value? In the official php manual about `$_SESSION`  I haven't found anything about that. I'll be glad if you could explain this script

Comment: `$_SESSION` is just an array that works like all other arrays. That code is just creating a dynamic key name. If `$_GET['add']` would contain the string `foo`, then it would be the same as: `$_SESSION['prodotto_foo']`. Just having that on it's own would be useless though. You should either get the value: `$theValue = $_SESSION[....]` or setting it: `$_SESSION[...] = 'foobar'`

Comment: As per the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php): $_SESSION is an associative array containing session variables available to the current script. E.g.: `$_SESSION['test'] = 42;` `echo $_SESSION['test'];` outputs `42`.

Comment: `$_SESSION` is just an associative array that holds the session values that You (or the one who wrote the code) put inside. So doing `$_SESSION['prodotto_'.$_GET['add']];` you are just trying to retrieve the session value mapped to the key `'prodotto_'.$_GET['add']`. And that means, that key-value in `$_SESSION` has been set somewhere else in the current or another script, by the one you wrote the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with `$_SESSION` itself. `$_SESSION` is just an array. The code does nothing:

```
$_SESSION['prodotto_'.$_GET['add']];
```

This is the same as if you were to make a variable and do nothing with it:

```
$myVar;
```

You are not setting or using the value, so the code is pointless.

---

**To set the value:**

```
$_SESSION['prodotto_' . $_GET['add']] = 'abc';
```

**To output the value:**

```
echo $_SESSION['prodotto_' . $_GET['add']];
```

**To assign the value to another variable:**

```
$prodotto = $_SESSION['prodotto_' . $_GET['add']];
echo $prodotto;
```

**To see everything in the $_SESSION array:**

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```